# Como foi definido quais eram as alturas maiores e menores junto com as taxas

Tags: javascript

```
function calcularCrescimento(altura1, taxa1, altura2, taxa2) {
    if(altura1 == altura2){
        if (taxa1 > taxa2) {
            return 'A criança 1 ultrapassará a criança 2 em 1 ano.'
        } else if(taxa1 < taxa2) {
            return 'A criança 2 ultrapassará a criança 1 em 1 ano.'
        }else{
            return 'As crianças tem igual altura e crescimento.'
        }
    } else {
        if (altura1 > altura2) {
            if(taxa1 >= taxa2){
                return 'A criança menor não ultrapassará a maior.'
            }else{
               return `A criança menor ultrapassará a maior em ${calcularTempo(altura2, taxa2, altura1, taxa1)} anos` 
            }
        } else {
            if(taxa2 >= taxa1){
                return 'A criança menor não ultrapassará a maior.'
            }else{
               return `A criança menor ultrapassará a maior em ${calcularTempo(altura1, taxa1, altura2, taxa2)} anos` 
            }
        }
    }
}

function calcularTempo(alturaMenor, taxaAlturaMenor, alturaMaior, taxaAlturaMaior){
    let qtdAnos = 0
    while (alturaMenor < alturaMaior) {
        alturaMenor += taxaAlturaMenor
        alturaMaior += taxaAlturaMaior
        qtdAnos++
    }
    //console.log(qtdAnos)
    return qtdAnos
}

console.log(calcularCrescimento(150, 2, 130, 4));
```

Comment: Qual é a sua dúvida ? Sugiro a leitura [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável ?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1186/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%c3%adnimo-completo-e-verific%c3%a1vel)

Comment: Desculpe não ser ser claro, eu não consegui indentificar como foi definido qual era (alturaMenor, taxaAlturaMenor, alturaMaior, taxaAlturaMaior) pois elas não foram definidas antes da função ser criada, então eu estou com uma dificuldade para entender como os dados foram organizados dessa forma.

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.